# How to fix memory card error on Canon camera?

Tags: canon, memory-card, sdcard

I have a Canon EOS 550D and cannot get two different memory cards to work.
The first one is SanDisk Extreeme, microSDXC 1, 64 GB and the second is a Verbatim SDHC class 4, 8GB.
The situation with the SanDisk memory cards is that the camera recognises it and I was able to take a few photos (30 max). Afterwards I get the err 02 ( Card cannot be accessed. Reinsert/change card or format card with camera.)

Regarding Verbatim SDHC, the camera does not even recognise there is a card present in the memory slot. Interestingly, It works with a microSDHC class 4, 8 GB card from a different brand.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can make those cards work with my camera?

Comment: Where are you getting your cards? There are probably more counterfeit Sandisk cards than genuine ones in the wild. If they didn't come from a reliable source, you might not be using what the label says you are using.

Comment: My two cents and well-intentioned advice: Get rid of these memory cards ad buy some new original standard sized SD cards. If your SD cards doesnt work properly than you have always the trouble of loosing photos or being not able to take some. There is nothing good about save some bugs on memory cards (besides normal sales discount), because these are the elements that brings home the photos. Btw. the last information I had was that there are tools to check if the sd card is valid and original or a counterfeit. But I doesnt remember the name, so google will have answers.

Comment: I have a cheap Canon IXUS and one of my two identical microSD's started giving me "memory card error" on the camera but both work fine on my laptop. It turns out the camera's "OS" is picky about the structure and contents of the DCIM folder. I think I edited some of the image files on the card on my laptop. Just renaming the folders was enough to get it to work. I did **not** have to reformat the card. I can't browse the photos in the renamed folders on the camera but everything is still there when I put the card in the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

For the one that's recognized, format it *in the camera* after moving all the photos to safe storage (e.g. flash drive or PC). If it does not work correctly after formatting, perhaps the card is defective or contacts in the camera to the card are loose or broken.

As for the 8 GB card, it may be too slow (class 4) or too small to use in the camera. Try formatting it as FAT on a PC. If that fails, the card is bad.

Comment: How can I diagnose if the camera`s card slot is damaged?

Comment: 1. Look inside - the thin gold-plated wires are easily bent. 2. Try using another card - if it works, the connectors are probably OK.

Comment: For the one that's recognized you probably won't have to format it. Cameras are just much more picky about the files on their SD cards if you use them in another device to edit them or the device just adds thumbnails etc. Just moving the files or renaming the folders should be enough. It was for me.